# reset windows firewall without deleting instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I accidentally messed up Windows Firewall of my VPS and now I can't connect using RDP anymore.
Is there a way to reset the firewall rules without deleting and creating a new instance? Already checked the FAQs and found nothing about it, same goes for the cloud shell. The firewall rules that I can see on the web manager seems different of my Operational System firewall.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Google Cloud console.

Go to the Windows Instance 
Edit the Instance and add the following key/value pair to Custom Metadata section

key is: windows-startup-script-cmd 
value: netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off

This resets the firewall to Off when booting and you can get back in with the RDP client as before.

Answer (score 0):

Please open [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart) on Google Cloud Platform web console.

Type: `gcloud compute firewall-rules create openrdp --allow=tcp:3389`

Try to connect your machine again.